# Call a function from withing a function

Tags: c, function

I am trying to build a **[CARDIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CARDboard_Illustrative_Aid_to_Computation) Computer** simulator in `C`, and I got to a stage where I need to call a function from within a function.

---

In the code below I am trying to call the function `JAZ()`, in the function `CARDIAC()`, and I get the obvious error saying that I can't call it since it was not pre-defined.

---

**What do I need to do in order for the compiled program to** `printf` *"Point reached!"*

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input;

void CARDIAC(int* ptr)
{
    int input = *ptr;

    while(input<900)
    {
        if(input<100 && input>=0)
        {
            // INP();
        }
        else if(input<200 && input>99)
        {
            printf("Point reached!\n");
            break;
        }
        else if(input<300 && input>199)
        {
            // LDA();
        }
        else if(input<400 && input>299)
        {
            // LDI();
        }
        else if(input<500 && input>399)
        {
            // STA();
        }
        else if(input<600 && input>499)
        {
            // STI();
        }
        else if(input<700 && input>599)
        {
            // ADD();
        }
        else if(input<800 && input>699)
        {
            // SUB();
        }
        else if(input<900 && input>799)
        {
            JAZ();
        }
        else
        {
            // HRS();
        }
    } 
    printf("Done\n");
}

void JAZ()
{   
    input = 180;
    CARDIAC(&input);
}

int main()
{
    input=820;
    CARDIAC(&input);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**This is the output I get:**

```
test.c: In function ‘CARDIAC’:
test.c:47:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘JAZ’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    JAZ();
    ^~~
test.c: At top level:
test.c:57:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘JAZ’
 void JAZ()
      ^~~
test.c:47:4: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘JAZ’ was here
    JAZ();
    ^~~
```

Comment: Does the order of function declarations matter in c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put function prototypes before the both functions, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input;

/* function prototypes */
void CARDIAC(int *ptr);
void JAZ(void);

void CARDIAC(int* ptr)
{
    int input = *ptr;
 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the `JAZ()` function before `CARDIAC()`

Comment: I will get the same message but vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to do in order for the compiled program to printf "Point reached!"

you have in your function Jaz input = 280; so it will not printed because 280 > 200 as you write in your else if statement  `else if(input<200 && input>99)`.

```
 void JAZ()
 {   
     input = 280;       //you must change this value
     CARDIAC(&input);
 }
```

and another problem that you have is your loop it will not end.

## edit

I don't really know what are you trying to do with while in that function, but If you want to end it `input` must reach 900 or higher to stop the while loop as you declare in your CARDIAC function `while(input<900)`.

here is a code that print "Point reached" :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int input;
void JAZ();

void CARDIAC(int* ptr)
{
    int input = *ptr;

    //while(input<900)
    //{
        if(input<100 && input>=0)
        {
            // INP();
        }
        else if(input<200 && input>99)
        {
            printf("Point reached!\n");
         //   break;
        }
        else if(input<300 && input>199)
        {
            // LDA();
        }
        else if(input<400 && input>299)
        {
            // LDI();
        }
        else if(input<500 && input>399)
        {
            // STA();
        }
        else if(input<600 && input>499)
        {
            // STI();
        }
        else if(input<700 && input>599)
        {
            // ADD();
        }
        else if(input<800 && input>699)
        {
            // SUB();
        }
        else if(input<900 && input>799)
        {
            JAZ();
        }
        else
        {
            // HRS();
        }
    //} 
    //printf("Done\n");
}

void JAZ()
{   
    input = 180;
    CARDIAC(&input);
}


int main()
{
    input=820;
    CARDIAC(&input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do I stop my loop?

Comment: @Avocado Your loop stops when `input<900` isn't true any longer. But since you don't change `input` inside your loop ...